# Project dependencies across different directories with cmake

Tags: cmake

Suppose I have such project structure:

```
Root
  + ProjA
     + SubA.1
     + SubA.2
  + ProjB
     + SubB.1
     + SubB.2
```

And the dependencies I setup is:

```
SubA.2 depends on SubA.1
ProjA depends on SubA.1 and SubA.2 
ProjB depends on ProjA
```

I want to make the build order looks like this when start with `make -jX`:

```
1. SubA.1
2. SubA.2
3. SubB.1 SubB.2
```

But the fact is:

```
1. SubA.1 SubB.1 SubB.2
2. SubA.2
```

It seems the `ProjB => ProjA` can't be used to make all the `SubB`s build after `SubA`s.

How can I make all the `SubB`s build after all the `SubA`s finishes?

Comment: Which kind of dependency do you have? If it's at link time, all objects of the depending project can be built and only the linking phase might have to wait that the depended target is complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CMake dependencies can be set only on per-target basis.

You should decide, whether `ProjB` depends on *internals* of `ProjA` or not. By "internals" I mean names of targets, values of CMake variables and so on.

1. If `ProjB` actually require internals of `ProjA`, you may carefully determine targets of `ProjA`, which are required for one or another target of `ProjB`, and set only needed dependencies. Such a way building of `ProjA` may interleave with `ProjB` with `make -j`, but building will be correct.

E.g., if `SubB.1` is executable, which requires `SubA.1` library for link with, then

```
target_link_libraries(SubB.1 SubA.1)
```

automatically sets needed dependencies.

If `SubB.2` is generated using executable `SubA.2`, then usage

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT <subB.2_file>
    COMMAND SubA.2 <args>
)
```

will automatically set needed dependencies.

2. If `ProjB` doesn't aware about internal of `ProjA` and it is only known that `ProjB` can be built only when `ProjA` is already built, then you may use `ExternalProject_Add` for build both projects and set dependencies between created targets:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
ExternalProject_Add(ProjA ...)
ExternalProject_Add(ProjB ...)
# Now `ProjA` and `ProjB` are targets in top-level project.
add_dependencies(ProjB ProjA)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have figured out my issue. No matter how the `ProjB` depends on the `ProjA` it has nothing to do with the internal `SubB`s. I have to set all the `SubB`s directly depend on the `ProjA` instead.

Comment: `ExternalProject_Add(ProjB SOURCE_DIR /src/ProjB DEPENDS ProjA)`