# Dependency between two subdirectories in CMake

Tags: cmake

In my root `CMakeLists.txt`, I have:

```
add_subdirectory(libs)
add_subdirectory(main)
```

In *libs*, I have my own *CMakeLists.txt* to build external projects.
In *main*, there is a *CMakeLists.txt* from another repository, which I do not control.

To build *main*, *libs* needs to be built. I do not know how to specify the
dependency between *main* and *libs*.

In *libs*, with my external projects *lib1* and *lib2*, I used `add_dependencies(lib1 lib2)` and I have *lib2* built before *lib1*. I did not find how to do that for
*main* and *libs*.

The difficulty for me is I have to mix external projects and subdirectories, and I did not find any answer or was not able to adapt them.

Comment: In CMake, you cannot setup dependency between *directories*. If  `main/CMakeLists.txt` expects some **library file** to be existed, then you have no other choice than create that file **before processing** given `CMakeLists.txt`. E.g. you may use  `execute_process` with CMake project, which builds `libs`. If `main/CMakeLists.txt` links with a plain **library name**, and your `libs` have a **target** with the same name, CMake will interpret that library name as a target, and adds all needed dependencies automatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Project dependencies across different directories with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029635/project-dependencies-across-different-directories-with-cmake)

Comment: @Kamiccolo I do not think this is a duplicate, I use what is in your post for the external projects in my project as describe in my post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I do not know how to use what you explained…

Comment: Hm, is this phrase "In *libs*, I have my own *CMakeLists.txt* to build external projects." means that you use `ExternalProject_Add` in `libs/CMakeLists.txt` for build your libraries? If so, you may also use `ExternalProject_Add` in the `main/CMakeLists.txt` for build the project from another repository. Because `ExternalProject_Add` creates a *target*, you may setup dependencies between targets using `add_dependencies`.

Comment: Hum I did not catch that but was actually trying this way! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I converted `add_subdirectory(main)` into an external project. Since it is not possible to make a dependency on subdirectories, I use directly the inner targets. With all that I got:

```
include(ExternalProject)

add_subdirectory(libs)

ExternalProject_Add(main
  SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main
  ...
)
add_dependencies(main lib1 lib2)
```

Comment: And You said that it's not duplicate :|

Comment: I am sorry if I am limited, but I was not able to adapt the other answer for my problem. Now that I have the solution I see what you mean, but it was not the case before… CMake is so obscure for me!